# Can't add Three.js mesh to a-Frame scene

Tags: javascript, aframe

I am trying to create 3D text with Three.js. It works with three scenes. I looked at the code for adding the mesh to A-Frame, but when I try to repeat it, there is an error message in the console:

> Error: Entity.setObject3D was called with an object that was not an
> instance of THREE.Object3D.

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('threejs_text', {
  schema: {
    // ...
  },

init: function () {

    var el = this.el;

    var glow = 7.5;
    var words;
    let text = "Some text"
    const loader = new FontLoader();
    loader.load( './js/GoodTimes.json', function ( font ) {

        const geometry = new TextGeometry( text, {
            font: font,
            size: 10,
            height: 5,
            curveSegments: 16,
            bevelEnabled: true,
            bevelThickness: 0,
            bevelSize: 0,
            bevelOffset: 0,
            bevelSegments: 5
        } );

        const material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, flatShading: true,} );
        words = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material2);
    
    el.setObject3D('mesh', words);
    el.getObject3D('mesh');

    });

}

});
```

Comment: I have problems with reproducing the issue, [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/5c1sLrnu/4/). Are there any errors/logs indicating that the geometry wasn't properly created?